# Unable to use two connection string in web.config file. One is EntityConnection string Database first and other one is normal DBConnection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, ef-database-first

I am facing problem when I am using two connection string in my web.config file.
One connection string is simple DefaultDBConnection which is used  for account controller. 
Another connection is EntitiesConnection string Database first approach. This connection string is used to process SELECT operation using my stored procedure and this connection string is completely used in separate controller.

When i use both the connection string. Only EntitiesConnection string works and the operations on account controller does not work.

Can any one help me to fix this. I have been searching from past two days but unfortunately i did not find any solution.

Below is my two connection string in web.config.

```
<add name="DefaultDBConnection" connectionString="Data Source=xyz;Initial Catalog=My_DB;User ID=abc;pwd=abc123" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> 

<add name="EntitiesConnection" connectionString="metadata=res://*/EntityModel.Model1.csdl|res://*/EntityModel.Model1.ssdl|res://*/EntityModel.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=xyz;initial catalog=My_DB;user id=abc;password=abc123;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: Actually i want to make "DefaultDBConnection" as my default connection string that should work for all my applications controller and "EntitiesConnection" should only work for specific controller.

Comment: Is it the same database?

Comment: Yes database is same

Answer (score 0):

swap the names in the config make  DefaultDBConnection ==EntitiesConnection   and EntitiesConnection ==DefaultDBConnection

Comment: Are you saying to put the EntitiesConnection above the DefaultDBConnection. I swapped but it didn't worked.

Comment: When I swapped the names it didn't work. But then I put the "EntitiesConnection" connection string above the "DefaultDBConnection" connection string it worked. I am amazed how did it worked by putting the EntitiesConnection above the DefaultDBConnection. Can you through some light.

Answer (score 0):

Check `identityModel.cs` file in the `models` folder, whether base name is same as the connection string name,

```
  public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultDBConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }
```

In the web config;

```
<add name="DefaultDBConnection" connectionString="Data Source=xyz;Initial 
 Catalog=My_DB;User ID=abc;pwd=abc123" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: In DbContext base class I am using EntitiesConnection as my base class.

Comment: you mean inside `identityModel.cs` class? But it should use connection name which is target for account management. For entityframework you don't want manually enter any name in the code level.

Comment: Not inside the `indentityModel.cs` but inside the `Model.Context.cs` In Model1.Context.cs base class I am using EntityConnection. For Account controller I am not using  indentityModel.cs i am using simple ADO.NET crud operations.

Comment: However, placing the `EntitiesConnection` line above the `DefaultDBConnection` line in my web.config file fixed the issue. Do you know how this worked.